# How can I print all my database row from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print all the rows in my database say 'student'. I am trying with many of codes with while loops and even examples from w3school. But, it's not working. Here's a simple code of php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(!$conn) {
die('Could not connect to MySql'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("StudDatabase") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Student";
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

I am working in wamp server 2.2

Comment: Missing `from` in query it would be `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Student";`

Comment: What means "But, it's not working"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was editing my answer.

Comment: @Jens I tried all codes that was listed in w3school and it didn't work. I tried code to print all rows.

Comment: you never print every think.

Comment: And **STOP** using deprecated `mylsq_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

Your code don't print the result of the query.
Try to add this code:

```
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
}
```

---

But you should consider using PDO, [`mylsql` is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

```
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
foreach($database->query('SELECT * FROM `Student`') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```